# Problem import shapefile in PostGIS database

Tags: qgis, postgis, geometry

I am having a Polygon shapefile. When I try to import this shapefile in PostGIS some of the attributes in Geom Field is found empty. But in attribute table when I select that polygon it is visible in QGIS.

What is mistake I have committed?

Comment: Try validate geometry of shape-file in QGIS: Vector - Geometry Tools - Check geometry validity

Comment: @HasT I tried it is displaying no Geometery errors.What can i do?

Comment: can you in detailes write all actions when you import shape-file in database (tools, "some of the attributes in Geom Field is found empty" - how you see this). Try import these shape-file on another computer/or PostGIS database.

Comment: @HasT I imported the shapefile in qgis in post Gis using dbf loader in postGis.

Comment: With postgreSQL some lines may appear empty but they are not. Try the following query to see if the geometry is actually empty: "select * from your_table_name Where geom is NULL;". Then load your geometric table in QGIS to check the result or post the details attributes which seems to be empty